# Dnase data for GRCh38

Tags: bioinformatics, human-genome, chromatin, hypersensitivity

**This question below turned to be completely faulty. I don't have to do anything with DNase data for GRCh38.
I asked it because of the file count difference between hg38 and hg37, which I thought to be too big.
For hg38 there're 95 files **Peak.txt.gz*. For hg37 there're 236 **narrowPeak.gz*, but after merging pairs PkRep1 & PkRep2 (probably FASTQ(SE/PE) reps) we get only 123 files. Finally, this difference (123 & 95) no longer seems to be big and we have even cleaner situation without PkRep1 & PkRep2.**

**One again: there's no problem with DNase data for GRCh38 assembly and only my question was misleading. I'd like to apologise for the confusion I introduced.**

---

<s>I'm interesed in transciptional activity, thus I'm willing to use DNase hypersensitivity sites to detect regions where transcription factors are allowed to bind.
In previous genome assembly GRCh37 / hg19 I used to use narrow peaks files from these two sources (University of Washington and Duke University, respectively) (files with suffixes *.narrowPeak.gz*):</s>

http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/encodeDCC/wgEncodeUwDnase/
http://hgdownload.cse.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg19/encodeDCC/wgEncodeOpenChromDnase/

With the most contemporary assembly GRCh38 there're also some annotations attached (files with trailing *Peak.txt.gz*):
http://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/goldenPath/hg38/database/

And here four complementary question arise:

1. Consider only datasets, which come from University of Washington.
   For GRCh38 / hg19 I counted 236 narrow peak files, whereas for newer
   GRCh38 there're only 95 files. **How to explain this differene? Do the datasets represent exactly the same coverage, but with much lower granularity / precision (datasets that come for several tissue lines are merged into fewer files)?**
2. With GRCg37 / hg19 we have both narrow peaks as well as broad peaks,
   whereas GRCh38 comes with only one type of of file **Peak.txt.gz*.
   **Does it mean that with the newest version we have only narrow peaks? Are the broad peaks hidden somewhere else?**
3. With GRCh37 / hg19 we have two separate sources of DNase data: UofW and Duke. For GRCh38, it seems that only UofW datasets are availabe. **Is any other source of DNase data available, maybe stored separately (Duke or other lab)?**
4. **Let's suppose that you're in my place and you would like to determine cis-regulatory areas. What type of data can be used to do so? Mabey DNase datasets but from other source or even completly different type of data (NOT DNase)?**

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: No need to apologize. Your question was very interesting actually and it will aid the future researchers a lot am sure! I would suggest you to revert it to OP

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure that how much does it answer your question, but have a look at the homepage of [DeltaSVM](http://www.beerlab.org/deltasvm/) - In his work, *Lee et al.* have used similar datasets (only for GRCH37 I reckon) and I am sure they will address some of your queries.

As you yourself can better determine which dataset(s) are ones you need.